# React, Redux, Thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have been now struggling with this piece of code for quite a while, searching online through stackoverflow and the docs, and there is something I am just not getting...

I am basically using react redux with thunk. This is the code:

```
export function initializeApp(){

    return function (dispatch, getState){

        console.log(getState().weekending.weekending);
        const promisesArray = stateConfig.charts.map(option=>{
            return ()=> new Promise(resolve=>{
                ()=>dispatch(getChart(option,getState().weekending.weekending))
                resolve()}
            )
        });

        const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve =>
            setTimeout(resolve, ms)
        );

        console.log(promisesArray);
        return Promise.all(
            promisesArray
            ).then(delay(10000)
            ).then(()=>{console.log(getState().charts)}
            )
        // .then(()=>dispatch(appLoaded()))

    }
}
```

I am trying to create an array of actions that needs to get executed at the same time. I read with redux thunk, you can use Promise.all. I am creating an array of dispatch functions, which runs getChart, which is basically an action that pulls in the dataPoints of a chart and puts it into the store.
The amount of functions to get executed is based on stateConfig.charts which is the array which contains all the data needed for the pulling of the charts as well as the options of each individual chart.

When I do this, it somehow never dispatches the functions, I am not sure why. If I change the code around in any way, I get:
1) dispatch(...).then is not a function
2) Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

I think there is something fundamental I am not grasping here.

Any help is appreciated.

Ml, Vincent

EDIT:
After the help I got, I ended up with this:

```
    function appLoaded(dispatch){
        return new Promise(resolve=>{
            dispatch({type: ActionTypes.APP_LOADED});
            resolve();
        })
    }

    function getChart(options,weekending,dispatch){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            const {controller, action, payload } = options;
            payload.weekending = weekending;
            const SocketConnection = {controller,action,payload};
            console.log(SocketConnection)
            socket.emit(SocketRequest, SocketConnection, (data) => {
                const dataPoints = data.map((row,index)=>{return{x:index, label:row.name, y:timeToDecimal(row.value), labelValue: row.value, id:row.id }})
                    const payload = {
                        ...options, data: {...options.data.primary, dataPoints,}
                    }
                dispatch({type: ActionTypes.ADD_CHART, payload});
                resolve();
            })
        })
    }

    export function initializeApp(){
        return function (dispatch, getState){
            const promisesArray = stateConfig.charts.map(option=>getChart(option,getState().app.weekending,dispatch))
            const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
            return Promise.all(
                promisesArray
                ).then(appLoaded(dispatch)
                ).then(()=>delay(3000)
                ).then(()=>{console.log(getState().charts)}
                ).then(()=>{console.log(getState().app)}
                )
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `getChart` do? In particular, what does it return?

Comment: You can't do any async operation while dispatching actions. If you want to do async operation, there are lot of options available for middlewares. For example redux-thunk and redux-saga are the famous library for async operations in reactjs. For your reference https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk or https://redux-saga.js.org/

Comment: getChart pulled a series of dataPoints from the database and then generated all the options needed for the chart (using canvasjs), and then returns an object that can be reduced into the store.

Comment: @kumar , I am using redux-thunk, and that's exactly what I am trying to address here, how to use it to accomplish what I want.

Comment: @VincentRye so it synchronously returns an action? An object like `{ type: 'getChart', payload: 'somePieceOfData' }`? It will be easier if you just directly call whatever asynchronous stuff it is you want to do, with that async stuff returning a promise.

Comment: Yeah, it returned: ({type: ActionTypes.ADD_CHART, payload}), where payload contained the data from the database plus some default options based on the config file above.
How would I go about doing what you suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to dispatch an array of actions, i'd recommend you just directly do whatever async stuff it is you need. For example:

```
function initializeApp(){
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    const weekending = getState().weekending.weekending;
    const promisesArray = stateConfig.charts.map(option => {
      return doWork(option, weekending);
    })

    Promise.all(promisesArray)
      .then(charts => {
        dispatch(appLoaded(charts))
      })
  }
}


function doWork(option, weekending) {
  // maybe it looks something like this? Substitute with whatever you need to do, 
  //   and make sure to return a promise
  return http.get('someUrlBasedOnOptionAndWeekending')
    .then(response => response.data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I ended up with some new code, which I posted above as edit.